# How to increase the image size limit in yolov5? error: Image size exceeds limit of 178956970 pixels

Tags: python, object-detection, yolov5

i have some panaromic 360 degree images and i had annotated it for object detection. but when im trying to train the images , it shows the following error
WARNING: C:\Users\K\yolov5\data\images\blur\images\train\GCC9.jpeg: ignoring corrupt image/label: Image size (324768098 pixels) exceeds limit of 178956970 pixels, could be decompression bomb DOS attack.

how to mitigate this missue?
(image size 25486 x 12743)